# How to parallelize a MapReduce job in Hadoop and Yarn?

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, hadoop-yarn

Before anyone asks: yes my input is splittable, it's a 5 GB file and I get `mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:39` when I submit the job.

I have two datanodes, the first one is at the same node of master, the second one is live but only the first one runs the job.

In `mapred-site.xml` I have

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

as it shoud be. What am I missing?

Another issue is that on the master (that is also a datanode) I have 40 cores but the job is only using 2 of them, one per container as you can see in the image below.
[image]

I try to change every core-related property that I could find: `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores`, `mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores`,`mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores`, `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`, `mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum`, but still every job is limited to 2 cores.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to tweak these yarn parameters:

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores
```

From the screenshot it looks like your app is using 6GB of memory out of 8GB totally available to YARN. So there might not be enough memory to spin up another container.

Also, you mention you've got 40 cores. But the screenshot shows "Vcores Total" of just 8.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that